# IWiaDataTransfer::idtGetData fails with STG_E_MEDIUMFULL

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, wia

Followed Microsoft tutorial to implement an MFC GUI application, XP compatible, to read images from Canon MF6540 printer/scanner.

With lpszFileName in STGMEDIUM left at NULL, idtGetData is failing with STG_E_MEDIUMFULL.

With lpszFileName set to L"c:\tmp\foo.bmp", where "c:\tmp" is an existing folder, idtGetData is failing with 0xC0000005.

How might I please idtGetData? Thanks.

```
// WIADlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WIA.h"
#include "WIADlg.h"
#include "WIADataCallback.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CWIADlg dialog

CWIADlg::CWIADlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CWIADlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    m_root = NULL;
    m_scanner = NULL;
}

void CWIADlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWIADlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CWIADlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_SCAN, &CWIADlg::OnBnClickedButtonScan)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CWIADlg message handlers

BOOL CWIADlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WiaDevMgr, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWiaDevMgr, (void**)&m_pWiaDevMgr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format("CoCreateInstance CLSID_WiaDevMsg failure %08X", hr);
        MessageBox(str);
    }

    IEnumWIA_DEV_INFO *pWiaEnumDevInfo = NULL;
    hr = m_pWiaDevMgr->EnumDeviceInfo(WIA_DEVINFO_ENUM_LOCAL, &pWiaEnumDevInfo);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Loop until you get an error or pWiaEnumDevInfo->Next returns S_FALSE to signal the end of the list.
        while (S_OK == hr)
        {
            // Get the next device's property storage interface pointer
            IWiaPropertyStorage *pWiaPropertyStorage = NULL;
            hr = pWiaEnumDevInfo->Next(1, &pWiaPropertyStorage, NULL);

            // pWiaEnumDevInfo->Next will return S_FALSE when the list is exhausted, so check for S_OK before using the returned value.
            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                // Do something with the device's IWiaPropertyStorage*
                ReadSomeWiaProperties(pWiaPropertyStorage);

                // Release the device's IWiaPropertyStorage*
                pWiaPropertyStorage->Release();
                pWiaPropertyStorage = NULL;
            }
        }

        // If the result of the enumeration is S_FALSE (which is normal), change it to S_OK.
        if (S_FALSE == hr)
        {
            hr = S_OK;
        }

        // Release the enumerator
        pWiaEnumDevInfo->Release();
        pWiaEnumDevInfo = NULL;
    }

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CWIADlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CWIADlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CWIADlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

HRESULT CWIADlg::ReadSomeWiaProperties(IWiaPropertyStorage *pWiaPropertyStorage)
{
    // Declare PROPSPECs and PROPVARIANTs, and initialize them to zero.
    PROPSPEC PropSpec[3] = {0};
    PROPVARIANT PropVar[3] = {0};

    // How many properties are you querying for?
    const ULONG c_nPropertyCount = sizeof(PropSpec)/sizeof(PropSpec[0]);

    // Define which properties you want to read:
    // Device ID.  This is what you would use to create the device.
    PropSpec[0].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
    PropSpec[0].propid = WIA_DIP_DEV_ID;

    // Device Name
    PropSpec[1].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
    PropSpec[1].propid = WIA_DIP_DEV_NAME;

    // Device description
    PropSpec[2].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
    PropSpec[2].propid = WIA_DIP_DEV_DESC;

    // Ask for the property values
    HRESULT hr = pWiaPropertyStorage->ReadMultiple(c_nPropertyCount, PropSpec, PropVar);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // IWiaPropertyStorage::ReadMultiple will return S_FALSE if some
        // properties could not be read, so you have to check the return
        // types for each requested item.
        CString str;
        WIA_DEVICE *device = new WIA_DEVICE;

        // Check the return type for the device ID
        if (VT_BSTR == PropVar[0].vt)
        {
            // Do something with the device ID
            TRACE(TEXT("WIA_DIP_DEV_ID: %ws\n"), PropVar[0].bstrVal);
            device->deviceID.Format("%ws", PropVar[0].bstrVal);
            device->bstrDeviceID = SysAllocString(PropVar[0].bstrVal);
        }

        // Check the return type for the device name
        if (VT_BSTR == PropVar[1].vt)
        {
            // Do something with the device name
            TRACE(TEXT("WIA_DIP_DEV_NAME: %ws\n"), PropVar[1].bstrVal);
            device->deviceName.Format("%ws", PropVar[1].bstrVal);
        }

        // Check the return type for the device description
        if (VT_BSTR == PropVar[2].vt)
        {
            // Do something with the device description
            TRACE(TEXT("WIA_DIP_DEV_DESC: %ws\n"), PropVar[2].bstrVal);
            device->deviceDesc.Format("%ws", PropVar[2].bstrVal);
        }

        CListBox *list = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_WIA_DEVICES);
        int nIndex = list->AddString((LPCTSTR)device->deviceName);
        list->SetItemDataPtr(nIndex, device);

        // Free the returned PROPVARIANTs
        FreePropVariantArray(c_nPropertyCount, PropVar);
    }

    // Return the result of reading the properties
    return hr;
}


void CWIADlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}


void CWIADlg::OnBnClickedButtonScan()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CListBox *list = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_WIA_DEVICES);
    int nIndex = list->GetCurSel();
    if (nIndex < 0)
    {
        MessageBox("No device selected");
        return;
    }

    WIA_DEVICE *device = (WIA_DEVICE*)list->GetItemDataPtr(nIndex);
    MessageBox(device->deviceName);

    HRESULT hr = m_pWiaDevMgr->CreateDevice(device->bstrDeviceID, &m_root);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format("CreateDevice failure %08X", hr);
        MessageBox(str);
    }
    EnumerateItems(m_root);
    TransferWiaItem(m_root, m_scanner);
}

HRESULT CWIADlg::EnumerateItems(IWiaItem *pWiaItem)
{
    CString str;
    // Get the item type for this item.
    LONG lItemType = 0;
    HRESULT hr = pWiaItem->GetItemType(&lItemType);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        str.Format("pWiaItem=%08X", pWiaItem);
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeAnalyze)
            str += " WiaItemTypeAnalyze";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeAudio)
            str += " WiaItemTypeAudio";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeBurst)
            str += " WiaItemTypeBurst";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeDeleted)
            str += " WiaItemTypeDeleted";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeDevice)
            str += " WiaItemTypeDevice";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeDisconnected)
            str += " WiaItemTypeDisconnected";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeDocument)
            str += " WiaItemTypeDocument";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeFile)
            str += " WiaItemTypeFile";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeFolder)
            str += " WiaItemTypeFolder";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeFree)
            str += " WiaItemTypeFree";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeGenerated)
            str += " WiaITemTypeGenerated";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeHasAttachments)
            str += " WiaItemTypeHasAttachments";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeHPanorama)
            str += " WiaItemTypeHPanorama";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeImage)
        {
            str += " WiaItemTypeImage";
            m_scanner = pWiaItem;
        }
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeProgrammableDataSource)
            str += " WiaItemTypeProgrammableDataSource";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeRemoved)
            str += " WiaItemTypeRemoved";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeRoot)
            str += " WiaItemTypeRoot";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeStorage)
            str += " WiaItemTypeStorage";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeTransfer)
            str += " WiaItemTypeTransfer";
//      if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeTwainCapabilityPassThrough)
//          str += " WiaItemTypeTwainCapabilityPassThrough";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeVideo)
            str += " WiaItemTypeVideo";
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeVPanorama)
            str += " WiaItemTypeVPanorama";
        MessageBox(str);

        // If it is a folder, or it has attachments, enumerate its children.
        if (lItemType & WiaItemTypeFolder || lItemType & WiaItemTypeHasAttachments)
        {
            // Get the child item enumerator for this item.
            IEnumWiaItem *pEnumWiaItem = NULL;

            hr = pWiaItem->EnumChildItems(&pEnumWiaItem);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // Loop until you get an error or pEnumWiaItem->Next returns S_FALSE to signal the end of the list.
                while (S_OK == hr)
                {
                    str.Format("pEnumWiaItem=%08X", pEnumWiaItem);
                    MessageBox(str);
                    // Get the next child item.
                    IWiaItem *pChildWiaItem = NULL;

                    hr = pEnumWiaItem->Next(1, &pChildWiaItem, NULL);

                    // pEnumWiaItem->Next will return S_FALSE when the list is
                    // exhausted, so check for S_OK before using the returned
                    // value.
                    if (S_OK == hr)
                    {
                        str.Format("pChildWiaItem=%08X", pChildWiaItem);
                        MessageBox(str);
                        // Recurse into this item.
                        hr = EnumerateItems(pChildWiaItem);
#if 0
                        // Release this item.
                        str.Format("Releasing %08X", pChildWiaItem);
                        MessageBox(str);
                        pChildWiaItem->Release();
                        pChildWiaItem = NULL;
#endif
                    }
                }

                // If the result of the enumeration is S_FALSE (which is normal), change it to S_OK.
                if (S_FALSE == hr)
                {
                    hr = S_OK;
                }

                // Release the enumerator.
                pEnumWiaItem->Release();
                pEnumWiaItem = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CWIADlg::TransferWiaItem(IWiaItem *root, IWiaItem *scanner)
{
    CString str;
    // Get the IWiaPropertyStorage interface so you can set required properties.
    IWiaPropertyStorage *pWiaPropertyStorage = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = root->QueryInterface(IID_IWiaPropertyStorage, (void**)&pWiaPropertyStorage);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Prepare PROPSPECs and PROPVARIANTs for setting the media type and format
        PROPSPEC PropSpec[2] = {0};
        PROPVARIANT PropVariant[2] = {0};
        const ULONG c_nPropCount = sizeof(PropVariant) / sizeof(PropVariant[0]);

        // Use BMP as the output format
        GUID guidOutputFormat = WiaImgFmt_BMP;

        // Initialize the PROPSPECs
        PropSpec[0].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
        PropSpec[0].propid = WIA_IPA_FORMAT;
        PropSpec[1].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
        PropSpec[1].propid = WIA_IPA_TYMED;

        // Initialize the PROPVARIANTs
        PropVariant[0].vt = VT_CLSID;
        PropVariant[0].puuid = &guidOutputFormat;
        PropVariant[1].vt = VT_I4;
        PropVariant[1].lVal = TYMED_FILE;

        // Set the properties
        hr = pWiaPropertyStorage->WriteMultiple(c_nPropCount, PropSpec, PropVariant, WIA_IPA_FIRST);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Get the IWiaDataTransfer interface
            IWiaDataTransfer *pWiaDataTransfer = NULL;
            hr = scanner->QueryInterface(IID_IWiaDataTransfer, (void**)&pWiaDataTransfer);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
#if 1
                // Create our callback class
                CWiaDataCallback *pCallback = new CWiaDataCallback;
                if (pCallback)
                {
                    // Get the IWiaDataCallback interface from our callback class.
                    IWiaDataCallback *pWiaDataCallback = NULL;
                    hr = pCallback->QueryInterface(IID_IWiaDataCallback, (void**)&pWiaDataCallback);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        AfxMessageBox("calling idtGetData");
                        // Perform the transfer using default settings
                        STGMEDIUM stgMedium = {0};
                        stgMedium.tymed = TYMED_FILE;
                        stgMedium.lpszFileName = L"c:\\tmp\\foo.bmp";
                        hr = pWiaDataTransfer->idtGetData(&stgMedium, pWiaDataCallback);
                        if (S_OK == hr)
                        {
                            // Print the filename (note that this filename is always a WCHAR string, not TCHAR).
                            str.Format("Transferred filename: %ws", stgMedium.lpszFileName);
                            AfxMessageBox(str);

                            // Release any memory associated with the stgmedium This will delete the file stgMedium.lpszFileName.
                            ReleaseStgMedium(&stgMedium);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str.Format("idtGetData failure=%08X", hr);
                            AfxMessageBox(str);
                        }

                        // Release the callback interface
                        pWiaDataCallback->Release();
                        pWiaDataCallback = NULL;
                    }

                    // Release our callback.  It should now delete itself.
                    pCallback->Release();
                    pCallback = NULL;
                }
#else
                // Perform the transfer using default settings
                STGMEDIUM stgMedium = {0};
                stgMedium.tymed = TYMED_FILE;
//              stgMedium.lpszFileName = L"c:\\tmp\\foo.bmp";
                hr = pWiaDataTransfer->idtGetData(&stgMedium, NULL);
                if (S_OK == hr)
                {
                    // Print the filename (note that this filename is always a WCHAR string, not TCHAR).
                    str.Format(TEXT("Transferred filename: %ws"), stgMedium.lpszFileName);
                    MessageBox(str);

                    // Release any memory associated with the stgmedium This will delete the file stgMedium.lpszFileName.
                    ReleaseStgMedium(&stgMedium);
                }
                else
                {
                    str.Format("idtGetData failure=%08X", hr);
                    MessageBox(str);
                }
#endif
                // Release the IWiaDataTransfer
                pWiaDataTransfer->Release();
                pWiaDataTransfer = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                str.Format("TransferWiaItem::QueryInterface IID_IWiaDataTransfer failure=%08X", hr);
                MessageBox(str);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            str.Format("TransferWiaItem::WriteMultiple failure=%08X", hr);
            MessageBox(str);
        }

        // Release the IWiaPropertyStorage
        pWiaPropertyStorage->Release();
        pWiaPropertyStorage = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        str.Format("TransferWiaItem::QueryInterface IID_IWiaPropertyStorage failure=%08X", hr);
        MessageBox(str);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Please strip down the code to the absolute minimum, and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All the unrelated code is distracting.

Comment: Because I do not know why the code is failing, although it is to the best of my knowledge an exact duplicate of the Microsoft sample code, I thought it unwise to leave anything out. As I presume you are aware, COM functionality is deeply nested, and perhaps a COM reference that I am making not immediately adjacent to the call to idtGetData is faulty. For example, the Microsoft sample code in one place enumerates the "items" for a particular WIA device, and one of the "items" is a proper argument for one WIA method, and another "item for another WIA method. How to know where the mistake occurs?

Comment: Problem solved. My mistake [of course]. I was using the root device for the IID_IWiaPropertyStorage query, which "succeeded", but setup the later failure of idtGetData, which I called using the scan device. Once I used the scan device for the IID_IWiaPropertyStorage query, the entire scan succeeded. I have a BMP image.